# PHP calculate time remaining

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function

```
function getEndTimeRemaining($timestamp, $format) {       
    $difference = $timestamp - time();
    if($difference < 0)
        return false;
    else{

        $min_only = intval(floor($difference / 60));
        $hour_only = intval(floor($difference / 3600));

        $days = intval(floor($difference / 86400));
        $difference = $difference % 86400;
        $hours = intval(floor($difference / 3600));
        $difference = $difference % 3600;
        $minutes = intval(floor($difference / 60));
        if($minutes == 60){
            $hours = $hours+1;
            $minutes = 0;
        }

        if($days == 0){
            $format = str_replace('Days', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('Ds', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('%d', '', $format);
        }
        if($hours == 0){
            $format = str_replace('Hours', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('Hs', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('%h', '', $format);
        }
        if($minutes == 0){
            $format = str_replace('Minutes', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('Mins', '?', $format);
            $format = str_replace('Ms', '?', $format);       
            $format = str_replace('%m', '', $format);
        }

        $format = str_replace('?,', '', $format);
        $format = str_replace('?:', '', $format);
        $format = str_replace('?', '', $format);

        $timeLeft = str_replace('%d', number_format($days), $format);       
        $timeLeft = str_replace('%ho', number_format($hour_only), $timeLeft);
        $timeLeft = str_replace('%mo', number_format($min_only), $timeLeft);
        $timeLeft = str_replace('%h', number_format($hours), $timeLeft);
        $timeLeft = str_replace('%m', number_format($minutes), $timeLeft);

        if($days == 1){
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Days', 'Day', $timeLeft);
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Ds', 'D', $timeLeft);
        }
        if($hours == 1 || $hour_only == 1){
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Hours', 'Hour', $timeLeft);
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Hs', 'H', $timeLeft);
        }
        if($minutes == 1 || $min_only == 1){
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Minutes', 'Minute', $timeLeft);
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Mins', 'Min', $timeLeft);
            $timeLeft = str_replace('Ms', 'M', $timeLeft);           
        }

      return $timeLeft;
    }
}
```

and I am passing in a MySQL datetime field which is converted to strtotime

```
getEndTimeRemaining(strtotime($get_auction_details_result['end_date']), "%mo").
```

It will return the minutes i.e. 1 if there is 1 min left and 0 if there are only seconds left however I would like to know how many seconds are remaining i.e. 24 seconds remaining etc.

Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP are you running. Some of this is built into 5.3

Comment: Chances are you can do whatever you have in mind directly in MySQL, which has a very nice set of date and time manipulation functions.

Comment: I guess I could do it in MySQL however I already have all the data for that particular record already and thought there might just be a way to add a seconds count to the function.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need to reinvent the wheel if you are using PHP >= 5.3

Use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). The `DateInterval` returned gives you all the parts you want as well as has its own methods.